# Import CSV file with double quotes

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv

I have a csv file and I want to import to my MS Excel. In the csv files, some row have very long text with new line characters, therefore, I have to use double quotes for these text. When previewing, it can correctly parse my csv file. However, when I open the file with Excel, it cannot parse the file (please see images for more details).
I've tried to import the data with different separators, but it doesn't succeed.
Can you help explain?
Thanks.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Is a macro-based solution acceptable to you ??

Comment: @Gary'sStudent I would prefer a straightforward solution using software Excel, but a macro-based one is also OK. Could you please post your solution?

Comment: What encoding are you using? How are you opening the file (through the file menu or double click)? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668678/importing-csv-with-line-breaks-in-excel-2007

Comment: I obviously cannot test on YOUR csv file, since you do not provide it. But on a "mockup"  file with line feeds within a quoted phrase, the CSV file opens properly if I either Open the file; or double click on the file in the Explorer window.  It does not if I use the `Data/Import/from text/csv` wizard